# New file lost after git stash and then git stash apply in new branch

Tags: node.js, git

I've probably just lost 5 hours of work here... :(

I was on branch A: Created new file with other changes to existing files

I stashed my changes

Checked out master

Did pull on master

Checked out branch A

Did git stash apply

Did git checkout -b newBranchB

I then did git rebase master

Due to some conflicts I then did git rebase --abort

Prior to aborting and rebasing, I can see the new file.

I don't see my new file after aborting rebase! :(

Comment: Was the file tracked? Did you use the force flag?

Comment: updated issue. I did a git rebase --abort after trying to do a rebase with master. After this, I don't see my new file.

Answer (score 0):

See if `git reflog` has it.

`git log` records all commits that will be pushed to the remote repo.

`git reflog` shows all commits, even squashed commits - amended commits, overwritten commits, etc (but only since you last cloned).

```
git reflog

git reset --hard YOUR_REFLOG_COMMIT
```

I just hope you committed at some point!

Note that `git reflog` is a local reference and is deleted if you delete the Git folder locally. Unlike `git log`, which will be available if you delete the Git folder locally and then clone the repo again later.